# Export to Word in Stimulsoft doesn't honor NewPageBefore setting

Tags: c#, .net, stimulsoft

I have a report that I have set NewPageBefore setting on a band and in preview all looks fine. But when I export to Word2007 the band that has the setting does not flow to the next page as it should (and how it shows in preview). It just puts it right after the content on the previous page.

How can I make the export to Word honor the NewPageBefore bool set on the band?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the export settings. The `Remove Empty Space at Bottom of Page` setting should be disabled.